# kill subprocess if proc

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I'm using C++11 and linux. I am attempting to start up multiple ssh commands using fork() and popen() and monitor when the ssh command stops running. When I kill the ssh command on the other computer, it doesn't appear to kill the fork() child process that started it. The child process continues the run until I exit the program. What do I need to do to kill the child process once the ssh command which was called with popen() quits running? Is there something better I could use for this than popen() to call the ssh command?

Comment: run the program in gdb and caught the signal that is raised when the remote node shell is killed. i dont remember the signal that would be raised.

Comment: And how exactly would I do that?

Comment: in the shell gdb yourprogramname

Comment: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

Comment: Please, execute a "ps -aux" to see childs status.

Comment: You are calling `pclose()` when you're done, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `wait` or `waitpid` in order for the O/S to remove the child process.  A completed child process which has not had its status retrieved by its parent with `wait` becomes a "zombie" process.

If you're not interested in the child process status but only want to have them cleaned up, you can install a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, which will fire whenever one of your child processes finishes, and call `wait` within that handler to "reap" the child.

Comment: So put a wait() command after the popen() in the child process?

Comment: @user1620479: if what you mean is a wait() right after the popen() in the parent process, yes. wait() blocks the caller, though, so this may not be what you want: if the parent is not reading the output of the child process, the child will eventually hang due to full output buffers. Thus the signal handler may be what you need.

Comment: @user1620479: Alternatively, if you have some other positive indication that the child process is dead (e.g. the file descriptor for its stdout is closed), then you can call wait or waitpid then, in order to reap the child.

Answer (score -1):

child process should query the status of ssh process id periodically and based on response you get back, decide to kill it or not. you can use `getppid()` to get parent id.
After getting process id. you can check if it is active or not by using
below script

```
if ps -p $PID > /dev/null
then
   # pid is active do something
fi
```

Comment: I'm using kill(pid, 0) to tell me if it is still running. Even after I've killed the ssh command on the other computer, the process is still saying its running. So I'm still not sure how to tell if the ssh command has exited

Comment: "on the other computer"   If this  means the child is running on a different machine, then you need to send the kill signal to that computer.